# Can't see content on a Mac

Tags: mac

My account is an administrator. I use a Windows PC.

When an editor edits a page I created the content is blank.

She is on a Mac using Safari and Opera.

She is in Visual mode. If she clicks on Text mode there is nothing there either. It says 0 words underneath.

I changed the page so that her account was the author, but the problem remained.

Comment: Had you tried with your account on her computer? With her account on different computer?

Comment: @Rarst: I logged in with her account on my computer and the issue reoccurred.

Comment: Peculiar. Enabled `WP_DEBUG`? Any JS errors in browser console?

Comment: @Rarst: there was a PHP "memory limit reached" error. Increasing the memory limit resolved this error and displayed the content for the editor account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buried towards the bottom of the page edit page was a PHP memory limit reached error.

Increasing the memory limit removed the error, and the content was visible for the editor account.